# Method in base class does not exist during unit testing with mocha of Vue component

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, inheritance, vue.js, mocha.js

When I have a component in Vue that extends from a base class, it works in run time in the browser, as expected. But when unit testing with mocha, the method on the base class disappears. In the simple example below this results in the error `TypeError: this.methodInBaseClass is not a function`. But in runtime it works, then the message `Some other data` is shown, as I would expect.

What is going wrong? And more importantly, how to fix it?

Consider this simple Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>{{ myData }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import BaseClass from '@/components/BaseClass.vue';

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends BaseClass {
    @Prop() private msg!: string;

    private created(): void {
        this.methodInBaseClass();
    }
}
</script>
```

and the base class

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
export default class BaseClass extends Vue {
    protected myData: string = 'Some data';

    protected methodInBaseClass(): void {
        this.myData = 'Some other data';
    }
}
</script>
```

and the unit test

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
    it('Data is mutated', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld);
        expect(wrapper.html()).to.include('Some other data');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `Component` decorator to the base class so that the method `methodInBaseClass` can be declared as vue-object methods:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
@Component
export default class BaseClass extends Vue {
    protected myData: string = 'Some data';

    protected methodInBaseClass(): void {
        this.myData = 'Some other data';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Great. Thanks. But when I make the base class abstract, I cannot put `@Component` on the class anymore. But instead of abstract classes I will have methods with `throw new Error('Not implemented');` or so as a work around. Still I do not understand why it does work in run time, but not in unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to use `Component` decorator on an abstract class you can use the following hack.

Create a new `AbstractComponent` decorator:

```
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
export default function AbstractComponent(v: any) {
    return Component(v);
}
```

You will be able to use `AbstractComponent` decorator on an abstract class and get the same functionality as the `Component` decorator.